# Listbox ListFillRange

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

I have inserted a form control listbox on my sheet.  For some reason this errors out.

```
Sheet1.Shapes("ListBox1").ListFillRange = "A1:A10"
```

I'd like to fill the listbox with the range but I get a Run-time error '438', Object doesn't support this property or method.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is *Form* listbox, use this one:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("ListBox1").ControlFormat.ListFillRange = "A1:A10"
```

or with `Range` object:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Shapes("ListBox1").ControlFormat.List = .Range("A1:A10").Value
End With
```

Comment: I had to change .List to .ListFillRange and it worked simoco!  Thanks.  Didn't see .ControlFormat method in there, that's where it was hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use something more like:

```
Sheet1.ListBox1.ListFillRange = "A1:A10"
```

You were trying to find a `Shape` object called "ListBox1" and then run a method that `Shape` objects don't have.

Edit v2: I see, in that case a cast would be needed (and they work differently from vb.NET), I think this could work:

```
Dim myListBox as ListBox
SET myListBox = Sheet1.Shapes("ListBox1")
myListBox.ListFillRange = "A1:A10"
```

Comment: Compile error: Method or data member not found. This is a form control listbox, not a Userform listbox. Every other form control  I can manipulate properties with the Shapes object.

Comment: Where is your ListBox defined?

Comment: I have radio button options that I use: Sheet1.Shapes("Button1").Visible = True ... Works fine.

Comment: The radio button prob works because all controls have `Visible` property, but not all controls have `ListFillRange` method - see my updated answer regarding casting

Comment: Sub or function not defined

Comment: I forgot VBA doesn't cast like VB.NET, I've updated answer again, 3rd time lucky...