# Populate Listbox on a UserForm from a sheet after search based on a TextBox value

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a sheet called Sheet1 and I have a UserForm called SearchForm. On the form I have 2 textboxes called TextBox1,TextBox2 and I have a ListBox1.

On the sheet I have names, types of colthing, accession number, description how it looks and a few other columns that are not relevant for the question.

When I type a Name in TextBox1 and hit the Search button, I want the code to populate the Listbox with the values, that are matching with the typed in name. The columns that the data gets pulled from are not adjecent. I need the data from A,B,C,G.

The Listbox consits of 4 comluns.

I tried this code (watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EtEjGBllaOM&t=1114s) about it and copied from there):

```
Private Sub Keres_click()

Dim RowNum As Long
Dim SearchRow As Long


RowNum = 2
SearchRow = 2



Do Until Cells(RowNum, 1).Value = ""

   If InStr(1, Cells(RowNum, 2).Value, Me.TextBox1.Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Worksheets("Találatok (kereséshez)").Cells(SearchRow, 1).Value = Cells(RowNum, 1).Value
        Worksheets("Találatok (kereséshez)").Cells(SearchRow, 2).Value = Cells(RowNum, 2).Value
        Worksheets("Találatok (kereséshez)").Cells(SearchRow, 3).Value = Cells(RowNum, 3).Value
        Worksheets("Találatok (kereséshez)").Cells(SearchRow, 10).Value = Cells(RowNum, 10).Value
        SearchRow = SearchRow + 1
    End If
    RowNum = RowNum + 1
Loop

    Me.ListBox1.RowSource = "SearchResults"
End Sub
```

I did everything exactly like the guy from the video (except the Adding part), but im getting an error at the .RowSource part. The error is:

**Could not set the RowSource property. Invalid property value.**

I just want it to work like in the video.

Looked up a few other codes on this forum and on other forums, but they either gave no results or they pulled the entire sheet into the Listbox.

For the Textbox2 part I want to narrow down the results more, but I'm already struggiling with TextBox1, so I don't have a code for that part.

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of this two methods:

- 1/ Filter your data and copy the store the results somewhere in your sheet (as youd did). Then use `ListFillRange` property (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22760758/listbox-listfillrange) for details and code) to populate your listbox.
- 2/ Filter your data and import the results directly in your listbox, each time you have a cell matching the requirements (best solution in my opinion). Use `ListBox.AddItem "data"` for this. Look at [this page](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/controls/listbox.htm) for some code example, in "Multiple Columns" part.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the second part worked. I made a minor tweak to the code:

 ```For icount = 1 to lastrow```

But now I have 3 more problems:
1) only 1 row gets pulled in

2) the loop doesnt seem to work. If i try to autofilter the original sheet by Textbox1.Value and pull the data from the visible cells using SpecialCells method would that be better?

3) the listbox now ignores the first row. The data gets pulled into the second row.

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the new code and a picture of your excel table and listbox (if data are not sensitive of course) ? This will make it easier to properly understand the problems your are facing.

Comment: I already figured out the code. Going to share it once I have a bit of time. But i appreciate Your help. :)

Comment: @Gandalf96 Happy to hear that, and you're very welcome :)